# Can we skip the rails call chain when returning a 404 status in Rails Metal Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, http-status-code-404

I am writing a API for my rails app and I'd like to return the 404 code, for example, if user is not found. But whenever I return the 404 code rails takes over and end up giving me an error page with a 200 status(routing error). Is there a way to return the 404 and skip the call chain? using metal controller... I'm using Rails 2.3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and control the status to use. And additionally you can control what layout/template to display the 404 to the user. This should let you take charge of what status to use and not be strong-armed into using what rails thinks you need.

```
#app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    return custom_404_page unless @user
  end
end

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def custom_404_page
    render :template => 'layouts/custom_404_page', status: 404
  end
end
```